# How can I apply an image to a sphere with GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I would like to be able to look at an image as if it were glued to a sphere. Can I do this with GIMP?

btw, I don't care about what happens at the back of the sphere, just what I can see at the front.. In other words, I don't need the sides to join up on the other side, I just need the spheric effect..

Comment: and using http://blender.org to really map a texture to a sphere is not an option?

Comment: @akira I tried it, but found Blender quite confusing, plus I didn't find a tutorial which produced any result (tutorials that say Apply Material to Object without saying how are quite frustrating when trying to use a slow software you don't know)

Answer (score 6):

Use Filters --> Map --> Map object... and select Sphere.

Answer (score 0):

this is a little out dated, but when i tired it a few months ago it worked:

http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/gimp/globes.html

use this for reference:

http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/plugin-map-object.html